# trouble connecting to any onion sites

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services

I downloaded the Tor browser bundle yesterday, it opens fine, says I'm connected, and that I'm anonymous.  However, when I try to connect to any onion sites it will not access any of them, have tried multiple times to no avail. My firewall is set to allow Tor to run, and everything seems fine, untill I try to access an onion site.  It says timed out or something and unable to make connection. Can anyone suggest what is going on, and how I can fix the problem?

Comment: If you can't configure your client correctly, maybe you should just use a tor2web-Proxy. (onion.to or [https://onion.cab/](https://onion.cab/)) Are you able to access clearnet sites via tor?
Are you sure the .onion-sites u used are online?

Comment: Can you post your tor log?
Usually the issue can be seen there easily.

Comment: No reaction since June => So I close the question.